# Can't remove auto generated p tag from wc_display_item_meta (wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, woocommerce-theming

**Question:**
The following php code sends an email and the email result shows the following result.
Would you please let me know how to remove < p >< /p > or replace p to span?

**Why I need to remove it:**
I tried the css below,
but inline / inline-block only work with Gmail, not work with Outlook

**Existing php code (plugin created - quote-table.php):**

```
<div class="subtitle">
    <?php
    if ( $im ) {
    $im->display();
    } else {
    wc_display_item_meta( $item );
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

**Email shows:**

```
<div>
    <ul style="font-size:small;margin:0;padding:0;list-style:none">
    <li style="margin:0;padding:0">
    <strong>Type:</strong> 
    <p style="margin:0;display:inline-block;color:#8d8d8d;">Blog</p>
    </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS I tried (added it to the quote-table.php)**:

```
.subtitle p {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wc_display_item_meta` is located in the `wc-template-functions.php` file in the `includes` folder of the woocommerce plugin and will take two arguments. `$item` and `$args`. Within the `$args` you could pass in an option to disable automatically generated `<p>` tags, aka "autop".

```php
$args = array(

  'autop' => false

):

if ( $im ) {

  $im->display();

  } else {

  wc_display_item_meta( $item, $args );

}
```

Also if you need to further fine-tune your `$args`, here's the array:

```php
$args = array(
  'before'       => '<ul class="wc-item-meta"><li>',
  'after'        => '</li></ul>',
  'separator'    => '</li><li>',
  'echo'         => true,
  'autop'        => false,
  'label_before' => '<strong class="wc-item-meta-label">',
  'label_after'  => ':</strong> ',
)
```

---

#### Alternative way

Still can't get it to work? then try the following function which will remove all of the tags generated for your value: (Code goes to your `functions.php` file)

```php
add_filter('woocommerce_display_item_meta', 'your_theme_custom_woocommerce_display_item_meta', 20, 3);

function your_theme_custom_woocommerce_display_item_meta($html, $item, $args)
{
  $strings = array();
  $html = '';
  foreach ($item->get_formatted_meta_data() as $meta_id => $meta) {
    $display_value = wp_strip_all_tags($meta->display_value);
    $value     = trim($display_value);
    $strings[] = '<strong class="wc-item-meta-label">' . wp_kses_post($meta->display_key) . ':</strong> ' . $value;
  }

  if ($strings) {
    $html = $args['before'] . implode($args['separator'], $strings) . $args['after'];
  }

  if ($args['echo']) {
    echo $html;
  } else {
    return $html;
  }
}
```

Then in your template use this:

```php
if ( $im ) {

  $im->display();

  } else {

  wc_display_item_meta( $item );

}
```

I gave the custom function, that runs on the filter hook, a priority of `20`, this might not work since you're using a plugin which might use a higher priority functions. So if this doesn't work, then try to change the priority from `20` to, let's say, `999` to make sure it runs after your plugin functions.

---

#### Another way

Still can't get it to work? Then you can use `str_replace` function to remove the `p` tag, like so:

```php
$value  = trim($display_value);

$value_text = str_replace(['<p>', '</p>'], ['', ''], $value);
```

Comment: Hi Ruvee: Thank you for your help. I tried it and it works well with all tags (eg, it changes ul, li, strong to div) , but it just doesn't change the p tag. Email still shows P tag. Would you please let me know what else can I try? Thank you.

Comment: Hi Ruvee: Thanks again. I tried it, but unfortunately, result is the smae, it still shows p tag. I think $value part automatically creates p tag. I also tried both 'autop' => false / true, and both still show the p tag... wanna cry...

Comment: Hi Ruvee: I got an idea from you. I change $value_text = str_replace(['<p>', '</p>'], '', $value); in wc-template-functions.php. It removed the p tag. Thank you a lot for your supporive help. I wanted to vote up but I don't have the permission yet, sorry, and I selected your answer. Thanks again : )

Comment: Hi Ruvee: Do you remember the question about refreshing a parent page on closing a lightbox? Your code worked eventually, so I was going to select your answer but my account got closed (as I deleted my published questions for several times), so I couldn't select your answer... The only thing I could do was vote up on your asnwer... I'm sorry and I really thank you for your supportive hlep again. You are really a lifesaver : )  Have a nice weekend Ruvee : )